# creating a navigation with a jump menu

Tags: php, javascript, navigation, jump-list

im making a responsive website so when it is at mobile size the navigation turns into a jump menu, this is all fine and dandy!

but when is change pages on the jump menu whenever i get to another page the parent of the jump menu stays at the home page so i cant click back on the home page from another, how would i make it so say im on the home page and i click to go to the electrics page, on the electrics page the jump menu is ticked on electric?

p.s i cant change it on every page cos im pulling in the same nav bar on each page, below is the code im using at the moment

```
<form name="form" class="mob-nav">
          <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
            <option value="index.php">Home</option>
            <option value="how-it-works.php">How it works</option>
            <option value="gas.php">Gas</option>
            <option value="electric.php">Electric</option>
            <option value="telecoms.php">Telecoms</option>
            <option value="services.php">Services</option>
            <option value="contact.php">Contact</option>
          </select>
        </form>
```

heres a link to the site `http://79.170.44.126/rkhconsultants.co.uk/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it with some php

```
<?
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/index.php')
        { $page1 = ''; } else { $page1 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/how-it-works.php')
        { $page2 = ''; } else { $page2 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/gas.php')
        { $page3 = ''; } else { $page3 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/electric.php')
        { $page4 = ''; } else { $page4 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/telecoms.php')
        { $page5 = ''; } else { $page5 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/services.php')
        { $page6 = ''; } else { $page6 = 'selected'; }
        if ($PHP_SELF != '/rkhconsultants.co.uk/contact.php')
        { $page7 = ''; } else { $page7 = 'selected'; }
    ?>

<form name="form" class="mob-nav">
          <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
            <option <?echo $page1;?> value="index.php">Home</option>
            <option <?echo $page2;?> value="how-it-works.php">How it works</option>
            <option <?echo $page3;?> value="gas.php">Gas</option>
            <option <?echo $page4;?> value="electric.php">Electric</option>
            <option <?echo $page5;?> value="telecoms.php">Telecoms</option>
            <option <?echo $page6;?> value="services.php">Services</option>
            <option <?echo $page7;?> value="contact.php">Contact</option>
          </select>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to add the `selected` tag inside of the option element

```
 <option selected value="electric.php">Electric</option>
```

So you will want to duplicate the code that is adding class `active` on your navigation via PHP.

Comment: cheers for telling me about the selected thing, i used that with some php to fix it